# Select all instances of a double-clicked word using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am pretty new to JQuery.
I have a text in a div. When the user double clicks a word, I want to select all word's appearances. The problem is that I don't know how to refer to the selected word.
Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work: **http://jsfiddle.net/f3wzT/**

The code finds the double-clicked word and then wraps all instances of the word in a span.  There might be a better way to do it but, as you can see from the jsFiddle above, this does work.

Here's the code (quickly cobbled together from multiple sources):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSelectedText() {
        var txt = '';
        if (window.getSelection) {
            txt = window.getSelection();
        } else if (document.getSelection) {
            txt = document.getSelection();
        } else if (document.selection) {
            txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }
        return txt;
    }

    function deselectText() {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        } else if (document.getSelection) {
            txt = document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        } else if (document.selection) {
            txt = document.selection.empty;
        }

    }

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#content').dblclick(function() {
        $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        var t = getSelectedText();
        var regex = new RegExp(t, "gi");
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {return "<span class=\"highlight \">" + matched + "</span>";});
        deselectText();
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: that seems to work with a linked word. Doesnt seem to actually do what the OP wants.

Comment: You might be able to adapt it by putting every word in the DIV in a 'linked word' and styling it so it doesn't looked like a linked word.

Comment: You could put every word in that div in an <a> tag (not pretty I know) and then put a delegate on the div itself (I believe this is now called 'On' in the latest version of jquery) which can pass the text of the <a> tag to a function which calls highlight on the plugin mentioned above... doesn't seem very elegant though and will result in a lot of html

Answer (score 0):

There is a previous answer to this on stack that can be adapted from using paragraph to div.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643432/get-word-click-in-paragraphs)

You can change the alert to find the text in other places in the document and highlight them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that puts a span around each word and then highlights all spans that have the same text. http://jsfiddle.net/6xsNK/3/

```
$('.para').each(function() {
    var words = $(this).text().split(' ');
    var el = $(this).empty();
    $(words).each(function(i) {
        el.append($('<span>').text(this+' '));
    });
});

$('.para span').dblclick(function() {
    var t = $(this).text();
    var count = $('.para span').removeClass('hilite').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == t;}).addClass('hilite').size();
    alert(count+' match(es) found');
});
```